# How can I download a blocked attachment in gmail?

Tags: email, security, gmail

I have some documents I wrote, all of which are text, in various extensions, txt, .js, compressed and attached in an email. there was no issue when I uploaded the file several years ago, but evidently now there is an issue, I assume with the .js file. I would like to download the attachement, but I am blocked from doing so.Gmail claims there is a virus, but there is not.  Is there a way to download my attachment ignoring the security warning?

[image]

Comment: Hover over buttons in the yellow warning and also below that looking for “keep” or “download anyway “ Also try a different browser that may present options to you.

Comment: Hi, the following link might be helpful to you: https://medium.com/@NoriCode/retrieving-gmail-blocked-attachments-62ead0764792  https://support.google.com/mail/thread/10108563?hl=en